# How to write to worksheet.range with system.collections.ArrayList by Powershell?

Tags: powershell

when I try to write to worksheet.range with system.collections.ArrayList, It was failed, but because it was an One-dimensional array  when I transfer it to be system.Array, it was been an One-dimensional array, How can I transfer it into a two-dimensional array? or how to write to worksheet?

Error:

[DBG]: PS C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx>>
Missing parameter does not have a default value.
Parameter name: parameters
At C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\Desktop\txt2excel.ps1:148 char:1

- $ws.Range($startCell,$endCell).Value2 = $target_columns
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  ```

[DBG]: PS C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx>> $ws.Range($startCell,$endCell).Value2 = [System.Array]$target_columns
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
At line:1 char:1

- $ws.Range($startCell,$endCell).Value2 = [System.Array]$target_columns
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  ```

main code:

```
$original_file = Get-Content $originalTXT[1]
$target_columns = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList 

foreach ($ss in $original_file) { 

    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$target_row_temp = $ss.Split("|")
    $string_temp = $target_row_temp.GetRange(0,2)
    $target_columns.Add($string_temp) | Out-Null 
    $target_row_temp.RemoveRange(0,2)
    $target_range.Add($target_row_temp) | Out-Null 

} 

$startCell = ws.Cells.Item(11,2)
$endCell = $ws.Cells.Item(10 + $excelHigh,3)
$ws.Range($startCell,$endCell).Value2 = [System.Array]$target_columns
```

Comment: main code:
$original_file = Get-Content $originalTXT[1]
$target_columns = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($ss in $original_file) {
  [System.Collections.ArrayList]$target_row_temp = $ss.Split("|")

  $string_temp = $target_row_temp.GetRange(0,2)
  $target_columns.Add($string_temp) | Out-Null

  $target_row_temp.RemoveRange(0,2)
  $target_range.Add($target_row_temp) | Out-Null
}

$startCell = $ws.Cells.Item(11,2)
$endCell = $ws.Cells.Item(10 + $excelHigh,3)
$ws.Range($startCell,$endCell).Value2 = [System.Array]$target_columns